# Php: How to pull a value from an array in a single field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have a table named posts. In it, the columns are:

Postid - 1

PostBody - my first post

Likers - 1,2,3,4,5,

Now what am trying to do is, in the likers field, am trying to pull the individual number without pulling all the data on the field. So if I want to retrieve likers No.3, I want the output to be 3 when I echo it out.

I have tried FIND_IN_SET(), and strstr(). All I get is the whole array, 1-5,  being echoed. And because of that, I cannot match it with other variables(I.e. $var = 3;) which have the matching number.

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanx

Comment: You shouldn't have the likers in such a manner. You should have a different `post_likers` table which only has column `post_id` and `liker_id`. This way you can run a simple SQL query to find out if a user has liked a post.

Comment: Can you please show the query with `FIND_IN_SET`??

Comment: SELECT likers FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', likers)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way (read my comment first), what you can do is retrieve the comma-seperated data, explode it into a php array, and then use the `array_search` built-in function:

```
$likers_attribute_data = '1,2,3,4,5,';
$likers_array = explode(',', $likers_attribute_data);
// check if user 3 is a liker:
if (array_search('3', $likers_array) {
    // he has :)
} else {
    // he hasn't :(
}
```

Again, this is a very sloppy and inefficient way of doing business. Please just go with the solution in my comment!

Comment: The OP need the solution with mysql not PHP

Comment: @FrayneKonok He hasn't specified this. He also said that he tried using `strstr` which is a PHP function. If you carefully read the question, you can tell that either solution is acceptable to him.

Comment: @themessin this solution doesn't work for me. It's not pulling as expected